# Is using "Fortunate enough" wrong?

Tags: phrase-usage

> People who are fortunate enough to own a house in the city are very few.

The English quiz [here](http://www.bankersadda.com/2016/08/english-quiz-for-ibps-rbi-exam-201619.html?m=1)  suggests to remove *enough* saying it is unnecessary. Is it correct ? I have seen *enough* used in context of *sufficient* e.g. He is tall enough to be selected in military. But don't know why it's unnecessary in the above given sentence.

Comment: "enough" in the sentence can be considered redundant as it does not add any new meaning to the sentence.You could call it a *pleonasm*. However, I agree with @Andrew here in that both the sentences are correct and this correction is more of a nit-picking

Comment: Question 3,5, and 6 are also wrong on this test. I can think of a context where question 9 would work as written. The source is not reliable. 

One could justify their answer as a recommendation along the lines of Strunk and White, but not as a correction of something wrong. Their new version is also rhetorically weaker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's important to understand why the test says "fortunate enough" is redundant in this context.  The given sentence isn't saying that being fortunate is a *required condition* to own a house in the city, but rather a characteristic of those who do.  We can rephrase the example as:

> Because few people are able to afford a house in the city, those who can are **fortunate**.

The problem is that, even though it's slightly redundant, it's perfectly natural to express this using "fortunate enough", because there is little significant difference between:

> They are **fortunate enough** to own a house in the city

and

> They are **fortunate** to own a house in the city.

One says they are *sufficiently fortunate*, and the other says they are just *fortunate*.

It's "a difference that makes no difference".  But many non-native tests of English like to "split hairs" to hide the fact that the test makers care more about students' ability to *memorize trivia* than to their ability to learn how English is *actually spoken*.

Answer (score 1):

In NGrams, the phrase "who are fortunate enough to" is vastly more frequent than "who are fortunate to".

For me, the two phrases mean slightly different things;

- "People who are fortunate enough to own a house" means exactly what we want it to say: that you have to be fortunate to own a house.
- "People who are fortunate to own a house" could refer to a subset of people who own houses.  Some home-owners might be fortunate to own their homes, and others might own homes that cause them so much grief that they're not fortunate to own them.

However, perhaps I'm over-thinking.  Perhaps my interpretation of the second phrase is just my rationalisation of my aversion to the phrase "people who are fortunate to own a house" in your example.

For me, the version with "enough" sounds much more natural and is greatly preferable.

> People who are fortunate enough to own a house in the city are very few.